# Informatica to SnowFlake Database Connect

Tags: informatica

Can anybody please tell me how to connect informatica tool to [Snowflake](http://www.snowflake.net) cloud database or kindly suggest me if there is a connector available for the same.

Thanks :)

Comment: Hey!! Thanks for the edit :)

Comment: Please answer the question anyone who knows. Its really urgent. Thankyou!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are logged in to the cloud, on the top right corner there would be a "Help => Download", in the pop up window, download the drivers that match your connection style (JDBC/ODBC). Hope this will help.

Comment: Is theire any way to copy data from Informatica to Snowflake without using connector?